# How To Edit Single Record From Database?

Tags: php, edit

Code as of 20 January 2014

```
<?php
session_start();
// connect to the database
include('connect.php');
$message = $_GET['message'];
// check if the form has been submitted then process it
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Get data from table
//set the id manually for test purposes
$id = "429";
$forename = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['forename']));
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));
// check for empty fields and display error message
if ($forename == '' || $surname == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == '')
{
$message = "Please enter data in all fields" ;
header("Location: edit.php?message=$message");
}
else
{
// save the data to the table
mysql_query("UPDATE registration SET forename='$forename', surname='$surname', username='$username', email='$email', password='$password' WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error()); 
}
// redirecr and display message
$message = "Your changes have been saved";
header("Location: edit.php?message=$message");
exit;
}
$id=429;// this line could have been $id=$_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1")
or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
if($row)
{
// get data from the table
$forename = $row['forename'];
$surname = $row['surname'];
$username = $row['username'];
$email = $row['email'];
$password = $row['password'];
//dummy echo
print $message;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/forms.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cantora+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Voltaire' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />

</head>

<div class="container">

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="edit" id="editrecord">
<fieldset>
<legend><span class="headingreg">Edit Details</span></legend>
<div class="formreg">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>

<br style="clear:left;"/>
<label for="forename">Forename</label><div><input type="text" id="forename" name="forename" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $forename; ?>"/><br/></div>
<label for="forename">Surname</label><div><input type="text" name="surname" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"/><br/></div>
<label for="forename">Username</label><div><input type="text" name="username" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/><br/></div>
<label for="forename">Password</label><div><input type="text" name="password" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/><br/></div>
<label for="forename">email</label><div><input type="text" name="email" class="insetedit" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit2" value="submit">
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>

<br style="clear:left;"/>
<br style="clear:left;"/>

</body>
</html>
```

INDENTS REMOVED

I am following a tutorial for editing and deleting stored records in a database.

http://www.falkencreative.com/forum/records/view.php

In the tutorial one page displays the records in a database and another is used to edit the records :

http://www.falkencreative.com/forum/records/edit.php?id=33004

The problem is all the records in the database are displayed. What changes do I need to make so that I can display and edit a record based on a specified id on a single page? e.g.

$id = "429";

Eventually I will use sessions but for testing purpose I want to set the id manually.

I tried putting the code in a single page but got numerous errors e.g. headers already sent.

Here's the edit.php page with my attempt to set the id manually.

```
<?php
/* 
 EDIT.PHP
 Allows user to edit specific entry in database
*/

 // creates the edit record form
 // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
 function renderForm($id, $forename, $surname, $username, $password, $email, $error)
 {
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Edit Record</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 

 <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
 <div>
 <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
 <strong>Forename: *</strong> <input type="text" name="forename" value="<?php echo $forename; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Surname: *</strong> <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $surname; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Username: *</strong> <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>email: *</strong> <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>password: *</strong> <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/>
 <p>* Required</p>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </div>
 </form> 
 </body>
 </html> 
 <?php
 }


 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $id = "429";
 $forename = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['forename']));
 $surname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']));
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));

 // check that forename/surname fields are both filled in
 if ($forename == '' || $surname == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 //error, display form
  renderForm($id, $forename, $surname, $username, $password, $email, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE login SET forename='$forename', surname='$surname', username='$username', email='$email', password='$password' WHERE id='$id'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 


 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: view.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 {
 // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
 $forename = $row['forename'];
 $surname = $row['surname'];
 $username = $row['username'];
 $email = $row['email'];
 $password = $row['password'];

 // show form
 renderForm($id, $forename, $surname, $username, $password, $email, '');
   }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
?>
```

And the view.php page :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* 
VIEW.PHP
Displays all data from 'players' table
*/

// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// get results from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login") 
or die(mysql_error());  

// display data in table
echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>";

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Forename</th> <th>Surname</th> <th>Username</th> <th>eMail</th> <th>Password</th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

// echo out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['forename'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['surname'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['password'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
echo "</tr>"; 
} 

// close table>
echo "</table>";
?>
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

REMOVED FUNCTION AND ERROR VARIABLE

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// get form data
$id = "429";
$forename = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['forename']));
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));
// check empty fields
if ($forename == '' || $surname == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == '')
{
// generate error message
echo 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
}
else
{
// save the data to the database
mysql_query("UPDATE registration SET forename='$forename', surname='$surname', username='$username', email='$email', password='$password' WHERE id='$id'")
or die(mysql_error()); 
// Redirect
echo "Your changes have been saved";
header("Location: edit.php"); 
}
}
$id=429;// this line could have been $id=$_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1")
or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
if($row)
{
// get data from db
$forename = $row['forename'];
$surname = $row['surname'];
$username = $row['username'];
$email = $row['email'];
$password = $row['password'];
//dummy echo
echo 'formatting is messed up';
}
?>
```

Comment: *dated* tutorial, using depreciated functions

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM login WHERE id= $id"`

Comment: That is already in the edit.php code above.

Comment: It should also be in the view.php, since you are trying to only view the one id.

Comment: @Dagon I know. Doesn't matter. He's wrote one in mysqli as well but I don't understand mysqli so would prefer to get this working.

Comment: it will mater when the hosts upgrades, and your code stops working, or worse a new exploit goes unlatched and your server is hacked :(

Comment: @Sable Foste. Thanks. I don't want to see the view.php page! I want a single page that shows the fields based on the ID I set manually. In his example a user clicks on an id then a second page (edit.php) loads with the record for that id.

Comment: I don't get it.  After you run the query, you redirect back to the view.php page.  At least, I think that is what is happening.  Your code is really poorly indented, which makes things very confusing.

Comment: @Dagon It won't matter because it's not for commercial use. I have looked at mysqli and PDO and they are too difficult to follow without understanding basic mysqli. Once I understand that I can look at my code and re-write it.

Comment: @Sable Foste. I have removed the indents. Please click on the link and you'll see how it works. From the view page you have to click on an id then a second page loads (edit.php) with the record. I don't want to select the ids from a list as I will be using sessions so for the purposes of this tutorial I need a way to get to the edit.php page without having to use the view.php page. Once I can do that I should be able to incorporate it into my existing code.

Comment: @Sable Foste. Thank you. I will try this in the morning. I only have 4 rep so cannot leave one for you.

Comment: @Nullbreaker, by the way, the indents HELP.  You didn't have so many, you needed more.

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to replace the `$_GET['id']` with the code that provides the id.

If you are using sessions for example, replace `$_GET['id']` with `$_SESSION['id']`

In your code from the file edit.php:

```
// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Change to:

```
 $id=429;// this line could have been $id=$_SESSION['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Of course, in order to get to the point of executing that code, you would need to remove the conditional statements, since you are no longer getting the information from the `$_GET`.

I also added a `LIMIT 1` to the query, so that you only return one record; you probably would anyway, but if `id` didn't have a unique index (such as a primary key), it may return multiple records.

Also, in this example, you could nearly replace all of the deprecated `mysql_` references with `mysqli_`.  It won't protect you the way mysqli can with prepared statements, but it still should work.

Finally, the `renderForm` function is a poorly formed function.  You can only have one `<html>` declaration per page, and if you called the function more than once, it would have multiple declarations.

Comment: What's the alternative to renderForm? Also I want to display a message on updating. I've tried to use the error variable.

header("Location: edit.php");
$error = "You have successfully registered";

Comment: The alternative is to cut and paste the code inside `renderForm`, and replace the function call.  Especially in this case, where you only call it once.  Immediately following this paste (still inside your conditional `if`, add `echo "You have successfully registered.";`.

Comment: Thanks Sable. As I will be using a session to get the data is a function necessary? I've removed the function. I've also removed the error variable as it's not necessary. Everything works fine, error messages are displayed if any of the fields are blanked and a message is displayed once a user submits data. The only problem is the formatting is a mess until I click submit or put a dummy echo statement in after data is fetched from the database. I've marked it

//dummy echo

and added it to the code in the opening post so you can hopefully see what is causing this?

Comment: It is hard to tell; I don't see the `<html>` and `<body>` tags in the revised code.  The test page you have shown appears correctly to me in Chrome, and I don't see the dummy output on your final page.